# gnuplot matrix plotting with image at command line, why two e's required?

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

I'm actually plotting in C++ using a pipe, but a command line demo represents the confusion:

```
> plot '-' matrix with image
> 1 2
> 3 4
> e
> e
```

Nothing happens after the first 'e', but the plot comes after the second.  What does this mean?

And BTW, is there a way to set palette to grey on the same line (since I'm chaining multiple plot types together).

Answer (score 1):

Only one `e` should be required. If I save your script (with one `e`) into a file and then pipe it Gnuplot, it generates the plot as expected. I suppose the issue must be related to the way how you provide the data. For example is the newline after the first `e` correctly flushed to the output?

As for the palette, you can provide the command on the same line as the `plot` command if you delimit them with a semicolon:

```
set palette gray; plot '-' matrix with image
1 2
3 4
e
```

Comment: Is it different at the prompt?  I found a few other places with two e's, though the don't explain why it is needed, for example: http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/gnuplot-doc/htmldocs/image.html